# Different way to pass my_app.root_path to javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm making a mountable rails engine and I need my javascript to know what url the parent app has mounted me too. I can get the value I need with this in a controller.

```
my_app.root_path
```

I want a way for my Javascript to access this value. 
Is there a way to do this other than making a div in the html and accessing that with the Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used engines, but if I want a variable for my javascript, then I use something like this:

```
<SCRIPT>
    var app_root_path = "<%= my_app.root_path %>";
</SCRIPT>
```

If you put this, let's say, under `<head>`, `app_root_path` variable will be accessible to scripts everywhere on the page.